# Grabbing all 'special words' in python

Tags: python

To get the keywords in python I can use `keywords`:

```
import keyword
keyword.keywords
['and', 'as', 'assert', 'break', 'class', 'continue', 'def', 'del', 'elif', 'else', 'except', 'exec', 'finally', 'for', 'from', 'global', 'if', 'import', 'in', 'is', 'lambda', 'not', 'or', 'pass', 'print', 'raise', 'return', 'try', 'while', 'with', 'yield']
```

However, I am looking to find all 'special words' in python for syntax highlighting. For example, the word `dir` and `input` (`raw_input` if python2), `set`, `list`, etc. Is there a place that stores all the 'special words' in python -- keywords and elsewhere -- for the purpose of syntax highlighting?

Comment: Syntax highlighting isn't a part of Python. It's entirely up to your syntax highlighter. You can't retrieve this information from Python, because it's not up to Python.

Comment: You might find `import builtins; dir(builtins)` helpful. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642087/is-it-possible-to-get-a-list-of-keywords-in-python

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica: But Python certainly can be used to *identify* these words, which I think is the point of the question.

Comment: @MarkMeyer: Doesn't seem to work in Python2.

Comment: I think you'll find it's `keyword.kwlist`, in Python3 anyway, which is the only Python that matters now - you should *not* be using Python2.

Comment: @ScottHunter: You can use Python to identify "everything in the builtin namespace", but there's no guarantee that that's the exact list of names your syntax highlighter will treat specially. It's probably not, in most cases.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I got the impression the op was trying to *create* a highlighting function.

Answer (score 2):

These are called built-in functions. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20651249/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-built-in-functions-in-python) you can use an approach like this. You also have types (`int` and `list` for example). Add those to your keywords and you should have fairly complete coverage.

```py
import builtins
import inspect

builtin_functions = [name for name, function in sorted(vars(builtins).items()) if inspect.isbuiltin(function) or inspect.isfunction(function)]
types = [name for name, function in sorted(vars(builtins).items()) if type(function) == type]
```

Or for python 2

```py
import __builtin__
import inspect

builtin_functions = [name for name, function in sorted(vars(__builtin__).items()) if inspect.isbuiltin(function) or inspect.isfunction(function)]
types = [name for name, function in sorted(vars(__builtin__).items()) if type(function) == type]
```

Comment: You posted an answer you haven't actually tested?

Comment: This excludes things like `int` or `zip`.

Comment: Now edited to include types too (`int`, `list`, ...)